# Discord bot only working in pm, how can i fix this?

Tags: python, discord.py

This is the code, it only answers me in private messages but not in any group chat.

```
import discord
import random
import time
import asyncio

token = "number that im not gonna show"

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Bot logged on as {client.user}")


@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.author == client.user:
        return
    if msg.content.lower().startswith("?hi"):
        await msg.channel.send(f"Comrade {msg.author.display_name}, will you assist me in seizing the means of production?")

client.run(token)
```

Comment: If the site says you need to add more text, then add more text to better explain your problem. Show what you have tried, what Discord settings you have, etc. Don't just put in random characters, that is **not** well-accepted around here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the `message_content` intent, so you can't read messages except

- DM's
- Messages your bot is `@mentioned` in

If you'd like to read messages, enable this intent both in code and on the developer portal.

Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

PS. instead of manually trying to parse messages & prefixes, consider looking into the built-in `ext.commands` framework that does this all for you: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/index.html